# infinite componentDidUpdate() rendering after doing an update in React.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, rendering

I have a table where i have to update a specific field in each row. When I do the update the function i am calling (GET) to update the table automatically in comonentDidUpdate() is executed infinitely like this :

[image]

This is the view and when I click on one of the buttons to update the loop starts with no ending :

[image]

This is the code I've built so far :

```
const confirm = Modal.confirm;

class AccesConf extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            accesConf: '',
            test: false
        };
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (nextProps.accesConf !== prevState.accesConf && nextProps.accesConf) {
            return { accesConf: nextProps.accesConf };
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }



    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        // only update chart if the data has changed
        if (prevProps.accesConf !== this.props.accesConf) {
            this.props.getAccesConfAction()
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getAccesConfAction();
    }


    showDeleteConfirmation(value, idConf, record, thisHandler) {
        confirm({
            title: 'Voulez vous supprimer cet contact ?',
            content: '',
            okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
            okType: 'danger',
            cancelText: 'Non',
            onOk() {
                deleteAccesConfRequest(idConf);
                const { accesConf } = thisHandler.state;
                let accesConfs = null;
                accesConfs = accesConf.findIndex((accesConfs) => accesConfs.idConf === idConf);
                accesConf.splice(accesConfs, 1);
                thisHandler.setState({ accesConf: accesConf });
                NotificationManager.success("Le contact est supprimé avec succès !", "");
            },
            onCancel() {
            },
        });
    }

    showUpdateInfoConfirmation(value, idConf, record, thisHandler) {
        confirm({
            title: 'Voulez vous modifier la visibilité d infos employeur ?',
            content: '',
            okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
            okType: 'danger',
            cancelText: 'Non',
            onOk() {
                alert(idConf)
                console.log('idConfcolorAvant', idConf)
                updateAccesConfRequest(idConf);
                console.log('idConfcolorApres', idConf)
                const { accesConf } = thisHandler.state;
                //accesConf.splice(record, 1);
                thisHandler.setState({ accesConf: accesConf, test: true });
                NotificationManager.success("L'infos employeur est modifié avec succès !", "");
            },
            onCancel() {
            },
        });
    }


    render() {
        const data = this.state.accesConf
        const columns = [
            {
                title: 'Contacts',
                dataIndex: 'image',
                render: (text, record) => {
                    return <div className="gx-flex-row gx-align-items-center">
                        <img className="gx-rounded-circle gx-size-30 gx-mr-2" src={text} alt="" />
                        <p className="gx-mb-0">{record.name}</p>
                    </div>
                },
            },
            {
                title: 'Société',
                dataIndex: 'societe',
                render: (text, record) => {
                    return <span className="gx-text-grey">{record.societe}</span>
                },
            },
            {
                title: 'Dates',
                dataIndex: 'dates',
                render: (text, record) => {
                    return <span className="gx-text-grey">{record.dates}</span>
                },

            },
            {
                title: 'Infos enployeur',
                dataIndex: 'infos',
                render: (text, record) => {
                    if (text === "Privé") {
                        return <Button className="cm-comedien-button-prive"
                            id={record.idConf}
                            onClick={e => this.showUpdateInfoConfirmation(e.target.value, record.idConf, record, this)}>{text}
                        </Button>
                    } else {
                        return <Button type="primary" style={{ width: "70%" }}
                            id={record.idConf}
                            onClick={e => this.showUpdateInfoConfirmation(e.target.value, record.idConf, record, this)}>{text}</Button>
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                dataIndex: 'delete',
                render: (text, record) => {
                    return <span className="gx-pointer">
                        <i className="icon icon-trash gx-pointer gx-text-danger gx-fs-xxl"
                            id={record.idConf}
                            onClick={e => this.showDeleteConfirmation(e.target.value, record.idConf, record, this)} />
                    </span>
                },
            },

        ];


        return (

            < Widget >
                {/ {console.log("TesttttttttttttttNnnnnnnnnnnnnn", data)} /}
                <div className="gx-table-responsive">
                    <Table className="gx-table-no-bordered" columns={columns} dataSource={data} pagination={false}
                        size="small" />
                </div>
                <NotificationContainer />
            </Widget >
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = ({ comedien }) => {
    const { loaderUpdate, alertMessageUpdate, showMessageUpdate, alertMessageStatus, accesConf } = comedien;
    return {
        loaderUpdate,
        alertMessageUpdate,
        showMessageUpdate,
        alertMessageStatus,
        accesConf
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    hideMessageUpdate,
    showUpdateLoader,
    getAccesConfAction
})(AccesConf);
```

Do you have any solutions for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: console.log prevProps.accesConf and this.props.accesConf  to see if they are actually not equal to each other.

Comment: is `getAccesConfAction` changing the reference for `accesConf `?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are calling getAccesConfAction() through props. What does this function look like and are you doing any setState in that function in parent which is re-rendering the child?? This is one of the possible reasons because of which you are running into infinite renderings.